# python working with sqlite3 db, saving, updating and retrieving text from db

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I've been trying to work around this problem whole previous day. And almost succeeded. But still, I didn't get a clear answer about this - why the next code doesn't work?

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE t1 (name)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (?)", ('TEST',))
con.commit()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM t1")
text_ = c.fetchall()
text.insert(INSERT, text_)
text.tag_add('one', '1.0', '1.3')
text.tag_config('one', background='blue')

text_get = text.get('1.0', 'end')


c.execute("UPDATE t1 SET name=?", (text_get,))
con.commit()


text.insert(INSERT, '\n')

c.execute("SELECT * FROM t1")
text_ = c.fetchall()
text.insert(INSERT, text_)


root.mainloop()
```

The result is next:
TEXT before saving into db - has a background colour
TEXT after updating into db and retrieving it back - doesn't. 
Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text.get()` method returns only the plain text, but not information about any tags.

You have to use other methods to get information about the tags:

```
>>> text.tag_names()
('sel', 'one')
>>> text.tag_cget('one', 'background')
'blue'
>>> text.tag_ranges('one')
(<textindex object: '1.0'>, <textindex object: '1.3'>)
```

That information needs to be stored in some other column(s). Alternatively, insert formatting codes into the text saved in the DB.

Comment: @CL.Thank you. It works. Unfortunately it means a lot of code to re write... But for the future I will use it.